# MySQL query works through workbench but not mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am attempting to call my PHP class and run the function `get_group_count` which counts the number of groups for a certain user ID. The mysqli query uses a stored procedure that works in MySQL Workbench but not with PHP's mysqli.

Public function:

```
public function get_group_count($userID) {
    if($this->status()) {
        $db = Database::getInstance();
        $con = $db->getConnection();

        $pull = $con->prepare("CALL get_group_count(?)");
        $pull->bind_param('i', $userID); // line 19

        if(!$pull->execute()) {
            $pull->close();
            return false;
        };

        $pull->store_result();
        $pull->bind_result($count);
        $pull->fetch();
        $pull->close();

        return $count;
    };
    return false;
}
```

Error:

```
Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in ... on line 19
```

Stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE get_group_count(IN userID int)
BEGIN
    SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM groups WHERE adminID = userID) + (SELECT count(*) FROM members WHERE userID = userID) AS count;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

When calling the procedure through MySQL Workbench it returns a total number of rows from the `groups` table and `members` table.

Note: I also get the same error when attempting to run the query through mysqli rather than the stored procedure.

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

`$con` var_dump:

```
object(mysqli)#4 (19) {
  ["affected_rows"]=>
  int(1)
  ["client_info"]=>
  string(6) "5.5.45"
  ["client_version"]=>
  int(50545)
  ["connect_errno"]=>
  int(0)
  ["connect_error"]=>
  NULL
  ["errno"]=>
  int(2014)
  ["error"]=>
  string(52) "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"
  ["error_list"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["errno"]=>
      int(2014)
      ["sqlstate"]=>
      string(5) "HY000"
      ["error"]=>
      string(52) "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"
    }
  }
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["host_info"]=>
  string(25) "Localhost via UNIX socket"
  ["info"]=>
  NULL
  ["insert_id"]=>
  int(0)
  ["server_info"]=>
  string(14) "5.5.45-cll-lve"
  ["server_version"]=>
  int(50545)
  ["stat"]=>
  string(52) "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"
  ["sqlstate"]=>
  string(5) "HY000"
  ["protocol_version"]=>
  int(10)
  ["thread_id"]=>
  int(36623197)
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

`$pull` var_dump:

```
bool(false)
NULL
```

EDIT2: Ended up switching to PDO, everything works now.

Comment: Can you post a `var_dump` of `$con` and `$pull`? The problem looks to be with your `mysqli` setup, not the actual execution of that procedure call.

Comment: I think you should change that call to `select  get_group_count(?)` instead of `CALL get_group_count(?)` `Call` is client specific not for mysql drivers,  not sure though.

Comment: @JacobSee Added dumps; Jorge I think it should work either way

Comment: Line 18 should also return an error message if prepare returns false.

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL); try this before calling line 18

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the `$con` dump, it appears that the last query you're executing on this connection is not using its result. `mysqli` uses unbuffered queries by default, so you need to either fetch the result of the previous query executed into a buffer manually, or free the memory that it's using to make room for your new query, with either `store_result()` or `free_result()`, respectively.

Comment: Hmm okay... Let me have a look around, I'm pretty use most, if not all, of my queries have `store_result()` and `close()`.

Comment: All of the queries used before `get_group_count` follow the same structure `$pull->store_result();$pull->bind_result(...);$pull->fetch();$pull->close();`. So I'm not sure if those are in the wrong order or something else is wrong.